# "While True Loop" doesn't cause the function to execute again

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, while-loop, beautifulsoup

The title of the question is pretty much self-explanatory. I'm currently running the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import datetime

url = "http://www.val-de-marne.gouv.fr/booking/create/4963/1"
cookie_banner_selector = "#cookies-banner a:nth-child(2)"
guichet_21 = "//input[@value='5955'][@name='planning']"
guichet_22 = "//input[@value='5968'][@name='planning']"
guichet_24 = "//input[@value='5973'][@name='planning']"
booking_selector = "//input[@value='Etape suivante'][@name='nextButton']"
guichet_buttons = [guichet_21, guichet_22, guichet_24]
name_guichet = ["guichet 21", "guichet 22", "guichet 24"]
guichet_buttonsandnames = zip(guichet_buttons, name_guichet)

browser = webdriver.Safari()
browser.maximize_window()
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
cookie_banner = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(cookie_banner_selector)
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", cookie_banner)
time.sleep(5)


def availability_checker():
    for i, j in guichet_buttonsandnames:
        guichet_selection = browser.find_element_by_xpath(i)
        guichet_selection.click()
        time.sleep(5)
        booking_submit = browser.find_element_by_xpath(booking_selector)
        booking_submit.click()
        innerHTML = browser.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML")
        soup = BeautifulSoup(innerHTML, 'lxml')
        alert = soup.find('form', id='FormBookingCreate')
        alert_text = alert.text
        message = alert_text.strip()
        if message == "Il n'existe plus de plage horaire libre pour votre demande de rendez-vous. Veuillez recommencer ultérieurement.":
            print("No available appointments in %s" % j)
            time.sleep(5)
            browser.back()
            browser.refresh()
        else:
            print("Appointment available in %s! Hurry and complete the form!" % j)
            break


while True:
    print("Checking for appointment availabilty on %s" % datetime.datetime.now())
    availability_checker()
    print("Checking complete on %s" % datetime.datetime.now())
    time.sleep(20)
    browser.refresh()
```

With the intent of having the function `availability_checker()` restart itself every 20 seconds.

The first iteration goes smoothly as I do get a notification of whether appointments are available on the three booths I'm looking at. However, once the 20 seconds are up, all I get are the `print()` messages, as if the function didn't run again.

Could you please shed some light on what is happening and how can I solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check if i, j counters have reset when calling the function again.  Or give time for the page to load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using zip() will provide you with a generator and only yield the result once.
You can easily fix the issue by changing:

```
guichet_buttonsandnames = zip(guichet_buttons, name_guichet)
```

To:

```
guichet_buttonsandnames = tuple(zip(guichet_buttons, name_guichet))
```

Comment: Or alternatively you could add the line `guichet_buttonsandnames = zip(guichet_buttons, name_guichet)` to your while loop to generate it every iteration. Nic Laforge's solution would take fewer computations per loop though!

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Nic for the quick fix! Since I'm a newcomer to both Python and Selenium/BeautifulSoup, this issue was driving me nuts. Also, thanks Reedinationer for the alternative solution. I'll definitely keep it in mind. Cheers!